# Timeout when trying to send envelope with 16mb .txt file attached

Tags: docusignapi

I get a timeout when I am trying to send envelope with 16mb .txt file attached to Docusign REST service. Timeout is because I don't get response in the fixed timeframe I have for that operation (it is about 1-2min). Keep in mind I don't have problem sending envelopes with files attached up to the allowed limit of 25mb of type .pdf or .doc. This only happens for .txt files

I am trying to understand if this is happens because DocuSign REST service is having trouble dealing with very big .txt file or? Can someone help with that?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect it's because it is taking a long time to render that text to PDF.  Perhaps it's a lot of pages?  I'd suggest that you try setting the "asynchronous" attribute at the envelope to "true".  Per https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope.htm this should give you an immediate return and the envelope status will be "Pending" until complete.

Comment: Hi Jeff, please re-enter your comment as an answer so we can up-vote it!